# Adding Javascript resources in theme

Tags: lotus, lotus-domino, xpages

The css files are added on the Xpage correctly, but when I add JS resource it's not added, and I have no idea why? This is what i write:

```
<resource>
        <content-type>text/javascript</content-type>
        <href>addThis.js</href>
</resource>
```

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your content-type is wrong. To add a clientside Javascript library through a theme you need to use application/x-javascript:

```
<resource>
     <content-type>application/x-javascript</content-type>
     <href>addThis.js</href>
</resource>
```

Comment: If you notice below, Thimo Jansen has already suggested that, but it doesn't work. Thank you though :)

Comment: Thimo suggested to use text/x-javascript but that's incorrect and doesn't work. It should be application/x-javascript. That's also what the Mastering XPages book says.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about CLIENT side javascript you should use the following markup:

```
<theme extends="oneuiv2.1">
  <script target="xsp" src="/yourscript.js" clientSide="true" type="text/javascript"/>
</theme>
```

For serverside script use

```
<theme extends="oneuiv2.1">
<script target="xsp" src="*/yourscript.jss" clientSide="false" type="text/javascript"/>
</theme>
```

Comment: finally... Thank you for the tip, I thought that it might need the clientSide=true but had no idea how to include it. Anyways, this works flawlessly! :)



        `<resource>
          <content-type><script target="xsp" clientSide="true" type="text/javascript"/></content-type>
          <href>addThis.js</href>
         </resource>`

Comment: Now this is weird.
I have few javascript sources added on my Xpages this way, but one of them doesn't work!? It's loaded on the page, i can see that through Firebug, but it doesn't work. If it's added through the Xpage resources it works!?
What the heck is this thing...

Comment: Could you define 'doesn't work'? I think you should create a new question regarding that issue if its a js function which doesnt work

Comment: I have a <ul> menu, which uses a custom js library to work (slide, effects, whatnot). If I add the resource in the xpage directly, it does work, but if I add it through the theme, it gets loaded in the source but the menu doesn't work.

Comment: I believe that you can not reference a serverside library included via a theme in the beforePageLoad or afterPageLoad events because of when the theme is processed. This might be your issue here?

Comment: No. I have a client side js library. Which I'm not referencing via beforaPageLoad or afterPageLoad. The function is self invoking anonymous function, so I don't have to call it on every page opening, it calls itself by default. The problem is, when I'm adding it in the xpage directly through resources, it works perfectly fine. But that way, i have to add it on every single xpage. Now if I reference it through the theme that is applied on the database, it doesn't work, like the function is not called at all. When I open Firebug, i can see that the library is loaded though.

Answer (score 1):

According to Mastering Xpages you should use content-type "text/x-javascript". Have you tried that?